# Importing numeric data after changing decimal and thousand separator

Tags: powerbuilder, decimalformat, regional-settings

I am using powerbuilder 2017 and I am trying to import data from a tab separated text. The problem is our country's regional settings are set to `,` for the `sDecimal` and `.` for the `sThousand` symbols.

When i use the `dw_1.importfile` (powerbuilder's import command), we need those settings to be the other way round: `.` for the `sDecimal` and `,` for the `sThousand`.

If i change those settings from `intl.cpl` additional settings and press ok, the import works fine. Since i want to automate that procedure so that our users don't have to manually do it, i tried doing it by changing the registry values (also tried all combinations of those changes):

```
RegistrySet("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International","sDecimal", ".")
RegistrySet("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International","sThousand", ",")
RegistrySet("HKEY_USERS\Control Panel\International","sDecimal", ".")
RegistrySet("HKEY_USERS\Control Panel\International","sThousand", ",")
```

The values change just fine, even the window settings in `intl.cpl` show the new values are inserted BUT when i try to use the `dw_1.mportfile` the import fails with the exact same behavior as if the values were set to the original settings. I'm not sure if this is a microsoft problem or powerbuilder problem. I tried searching if `intl.cpl` writes anywhere else in the registry or in any other file but couldn't find anything with tools like ProcessMonitor and RegShot.

My main question is why changing the registry values isn't showing the same behavior with just pressing ok in the `intl.cpl` window? What am i missing here?

Any help/input would be appreciated.